# Make packery.js rows equal height

Tags: javascript, css, packery

I'm trying to implement packery.js to display a grid of various elements which works so far. The elements height varies, so when a single element in the grid is larger than others, elements from the next row 'dock' onto elements from the first row.

Is it possible that packery makes the rows height equal to the largest row-element?